# Strong Induction with an inequality.

Tags: induction

> For all integers $n\geq  1$, 
>   $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4}  \cdot\cdots\cdot  \frac{2n-1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n + 1}}.$$

Need help with inductive step.

> IB: P(1) $$\prod_{i=1}^{1} \frac{2i-1}{2i} = \frac{1}{2}  \leq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3(1)+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}$$
>   IH: For some $k \geq 1$, assume P(K) is true. P(K) = $$\prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{2i-1}{2i} \leq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+1}}$$

Comment: Show us what you have done already!

Comment: So, assuming that $P(k)$ holds, what happens with $P(k+1)$?

Answer (score 0):

the beginning: $n=1$ then we have $\frac{1}{2}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}$ and this is true.
assuming for $n=k$ we have
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot ...\cdot \frac{2k-1}{2k}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+1}}$$
and we have to prove that for $n=k+1$ is hold:
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot ...\cdot \frac{2k-1}{2k}\cdot \frac{2k+1}{2(k+1)}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+4}}$$
we have to Show that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+1}}\cdot \frac{2k+1}{2(k+1)}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+4}}$$
which is true.
the last inequality is given by squaring as
$$(3k+4)(2k+1)^2\le 4(k+1)^2(3k+1)$$

Comment: it is just corrected, thank you for your hint!

Answer (score 0):

For the inductive step, note that that for $n\geq 1$,
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{2i-1}{2i}= \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{2i-1}{2i} \cdot \frac{2(n+1)-1}{2(n+1)}\leq   \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n + 1}}\cdot \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}.$$
So it remains to show that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n + 1}}\cdot \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1) + 1}}.$$
that is
$$(3n+4)(2n+1)^2 \leq (3n+1)(2n+2)^2.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: This is actually where I get stuck.

Comment: Eliminate the denominators, expand and simplify. What do you get?

Comment: Oh ok i see what you did. I think I can finish it from there.

Comment: @Arualia Let me know if everything will be okay in the end.

Comment: (12k^3 + 28k^2 + 19k + 4) \leq (12k^3 + 28k^2 + 20k + 4)

Comment: Correct! Are we happy?

Comment: YES!!! Thanks so much.